# Route Post#TOKEN instead of Post#ID in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've come a long way in my rails application & am 95% complete. The last thing I need to do is to restrict certain posts to certain users by generating a token that I send to specific users. I know that there are other ways to restrict access,(without getting too detailed) but for this application, it has to use tokens.

**How can I get my routing setup to look like this `post#token_string` instead of this `post#id`?**

Further info:
I already have `restrict_access` in a "private" method in my posts controller. My post model `has_many link_tokens` & my link_tokens model `belongs_to post` because there will be many link_tokens for one post

Any light shed would be appreciated. Thank you in advance (I can't wait to wrap this application up)

Right now, I have it like this `link_to post.name, post_url + "?token=" + @token.token` which results `http://localhost:3000/post/1?token=25b8af`

**error** message when using `find_by_token` (`http://localhost:3000/post/25b8af`)

```
def show
     **@post = LinkToken.find_by_token(params[:token]).post**
     @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I can think of is using custom routes instead of `resources`:

```
match 'posts' => 'posts#index', :via => :get
match 'posts' => 'posts#create', :via => :post
match 'posts/:token' => 'posts#show', :via => :get
match 'posts/:token' => 'posts#update', :via => :put
match 'posts/:token' => 'posts#destroy', :via => :delete
match 'posts/:token/new' => 'posts#new', :via => :get
match 'posts/:token/edit' => 'posts#edit', :via => :get
```

Then adapt your `PostsController` to find the posts by token instead of id:

```
def show
  @post = LinkToken.find_by_token(params[:token]).post
end
```

Comment: I just need the posts#show to have the token. I'm trying this out now & will report back with what I get. Thank you for taking the time to answer, @alfonso

Comment: getting undefined method `post' @alfonso

Comment: just edited in the full error message in my original question above @alfonso

Comment: @Jon Your url is wrong. It should be formatted like this: `http://localhost:3000/posts/25b8af`.

Comment: that's what I'm doing @alfonso. Could its being how it's generated? I'm generating it in another controller. It saves after the user fills out some information & then the token is generated

Comment: I meant "created" not generated". It's being generated in it's own model

Comment: @Jon it shouldn't matter how you create it. Here are a couple more things to check: 1. open a rails console and type `LinkToken.find_by_token('25b8af')`. 2. when you get the error in the browser, go to the parameters section and check that the token is being passed correctly.

Comment: @alfonso Not quite nice. You're not efficiently utilizing router methods. Does anyone know how to do the same with the minimal amount of code?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the `param` parameter in your resources:

```
resources user, param: :token
```

Leading to these routes

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:token/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:token(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:token(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:token(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:token(.:format)      users#destroy
     root GET    /                            application#index
```

Comment: I tried this and very simple. It worked but my `update action` throws NoMethod Error.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question has been asked, but for the books:

You could try to overwrite the to_param method in the model:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

Whatever the method returns is taken instead of id (for example in the path helpers).

See http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url for a detailed explanation.