# How to make my RESTful show action show token instead of ID

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I created a website with Ruby on Rails, which I believe is vulnerable and easy to scrape since ids are shown in the URL.

When I click on each lawyer which is managed by my `show-action` in my controller, the RESTful url shows http://localhost:3000/lawyers/1. The 1 in this case is the ID of the lawyer on my lawyers table.

> **Question:**
>
> How do I show token instead of id when a particular entry is viewed
>   with show action? Such the I have something like http://localhost:3000/lawyers/92a5e084-d660-41a7-98d7-cb8075797591

**Note**

Every lawyer on the lawyers table has a unique token.

Here are my code:

**lawyers_controller.rb**

```
class LawyersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_lawyer, only: [:show, :edit, :preview, :destroy]


  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json {render json: @lawyer }
      format.xml {render xml: @lawyer }
    end
  end


  private

  def get_lawyer
    @lawyer = Lawyer.find(params[:id])
  end


  def law_params
    params.require(:lawyer).permit(:name, :category_id,
                                   :image, :title, :category_id,
                                   :phone_number, :website, :email,
                                   :twitter_link, :linkedin_link,
                                   :professional_details, :published,
                                   :token, :remove_image )
  end

end
```

**route.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount RedactorRails::Engine => '/redactor_rails'
  root 'lawyers#index'


  resources :lawyers, except: [:index, :new]
  get 'lawyers/:id/preview' => 'lawyers#preview', as: :preview_lawyer
  get 'new' => 'lawyers#new', as: :new
end
```

**lawyer.rb**

```
class Lawyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :image,
            :name,
            :title,
            :category_id,
            :website,
            :email,
            presence: true
  validates :professional_details, length: { minimum: 300 }
  #validates :website, format: URI::regexp(%w(http https))

  validates_formatting_of :email, using: :email

  before_create :add_token
  before_save :format_lawyer_url



  def its_published?
    (!(self.published == nil))
  end


  private

  def add_token
    self.token = SecureRandom.uuid
  end

  def format_lawyer_url
    unless website =~ URI::regexp(%w(http https))
      add_http_prefix
    end
  end

  def add_http_prefix
    if website
      self.website = "http://#{self.website}"
    end
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160909121118) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "parent_id"
  end

  create_table "lawyers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "email",                default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "phone_number"
    t.text     "professional_details"
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "twitter_link"
    t.string   "linkedin_link"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "token"
    t.boolean  "published"
  end

  add_index "lawyers", ["category_id"], name: "index_lawyers_on_category_id"
  add_index "lawyers", ["email"], name: "index_lawyers_on_email"
  add_index "lawyers", ["name"], name: "index_lawyers_on_name"
  add_index "lawyers", ["phone_number"], name: "index_lawyers_on_phone_number"
  add_index "lawyers", ["published"], name: "index_lawyers_on_published"
  add_index "lawyers", ["token"], name: "index_lawyers_on_token"
end
```

**Note**: As suggested from the comments below, I have tried solutions posted there. i.e. [Route Post#TOKEN instead of Post#ID in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904711/route-posttoken-instead-of-postid-in-rails) but I will not go with it.

Why?

1. It makes my code error prone.
2. My interest is only to show `token` on my show action and not `id`.
3. The last answer which suggested I overwrite the to_param method in the model, works using this:

   ```
   def to_param
     "#{id}-#{token}"
   end
   ```

   but still doesn't make my code not vulnerable to parse by Scrappers.
   Any tech savy guy could easily copy the database table because it still adds the `id`.

Comment: Hmmm... edit either the `get_lawyer` method or the `show` method?

Comment: @Myst Yes something like that. My `get_lawyer` actually works with params id.

Comment: Either use `Lawyer.where token: params[:id]` or change the route so it's `params[:token]`, which will also fix all your `url_for` calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Route Post#TOKEN instead of Post#ID in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904711/route-posttoken-instead-of-postid-in-rails)

Comment: What do you think that showing ID's makes you vulnerable to? Scraping? If it's scraping then there is no real way to avoid it. If you link to each page from somewhere else the scrapers will use that. If you are just looking for increased security, security by obscurity is rarely the way to go.

Comment: @thesecretmaster, actually am not so sure if the token could be parsed still by Scrapper and copy out the database. Though I never tried but security wise, I believe someone could easily set an array on :id and use it to populate listing on the database. Nevertheless, you might wanna explain security by obscurity and a way to go about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to solve the problem:

In my **model**, I overwrite the `to_param` method such that I append it to `token`:

```
  def to_param # overridden
    token
  end
```

Though still leaves me with a tricky bug of `NoMethodError in Lawyers#show` when I go to vulnerable URLs such as `http://localhost:3000/lawyers/7` which corresponds to showing lawyer with id 7.

I afterall had a better solution using this Railscast Revised Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=963wTp9FCn4